# how to make shortcuts for the start and end of a "gather" environment

Tags: amsmath, shortcut

I am using sharelatex and found this weird behavior. On the code below, the first two equations don't compile, while the last two do.

Since these ways don't work, can anyone tell me another way to make a shortcut to the `gather` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\bg{\begin{gather}}
\def\eg{\end{gather}}
\newcommand{\bgat}{\begin{gather}}
\newcommand{\egat}{\end{gather}}
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}

\begin{document}\noindent

try \#1
    \bgat
        2 + 2 = 4\\
        \frac{\sqrt{y}}{x^2} = a
    \egat

try \#2
    \bg
        2 + 2 = 4\\
        \frac{\sqrt{y}}{x^2} = a
    \eg

try \#3
    \be
        2 + 2 = 4
    \ee

try \#4
    \begin{gather}
        2 + 2 = 4\\
        \frac{\sqrt{y}}{x^2} = a
    \end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The best shortcut would be to configure your editor to type the full environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: the amsmath documentation explicitly documents that you can not do this.

Comment: What is the purpose of your "shortcut"?

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT DO THIS!** Anyone reading your code (including you yourself in couple years time) will thank you for it!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, would you mind supplying a link to the page that says that? I'm a noob at latex and I'm having difficulties finding it on my own. Thanks.

Comment: @yo', thanks for the warning, I can totaly see where you are coming from. In this case I'll take my chances for it is obviously a mathematical enviroment wrapping around most equations.

Comment: you will have it already  `texdoc technote` will open the documentation then see section 6 "why can't I use abbreviations"... or [see the file here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/technote.pdf) but it is a bad idea to hide environment syntax even for environments where it works.

Comment: @ivbc it may be obvious to _you_ but it makes it far less obvious to other readers, and it makes it less obvious to your editor, for example I can select an environment or change from align to align* or gather or whatever with a few keystrokes as the editor knows the environment syntax, if you change to `\bg`, `\eg` it can not select the environment or syntax highlight the contents as mathematics or do anything useful.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I usualy play a lot with my enviroments changing Align to Gather and adding or removing *. It's annoying to have to hunt down the "\end"s and copy-paste the new enviroment. You seem to imply there is a better way to do it... whats it?

Comment: @ivbc: Oh, but this is a *completely different* problem!  It *is* possible to define a custom *environment* that you can redefine, once and for all, as, say, either `gather` or `gather*`; indeed, while `\newenvironment*{bg}{\begin{gather}}{\end{gather}}` does not compile, `\newenvironment*{bg}{\gather}{\endgather}` works as expected, and you can subsequently change the definition to `\newenvironment*{bg}{\csname gather*\endcsname}{\endgather}` (note that `\csname endgather*\endcsname` is the same as `\endgather`).  Are you interested in an answer going in this directon?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti, hi! I am interest yes. But would you mind adding some explanantion to why this would be better than, say, TH's method?

Comment: it depends on your editor, auctex (emacs) has commands to change the name of the current enviornment, or add environments, so it would take less keystokes to add `\begin{align} \end{align}` than \ba got to end ... \ea

Comment: @ivbc: The benefit is that a markup like, say, `\begin{myg} ... \end{myg}` integrates into LaTeX’s environment system, taking advantage of its name-checking facilities; thus, if you misspell the name `myg` in the `\end` declaration, you’ll get a meaningful error message.  On the other hand, if you misspell an argument delimiter, (La)TeX will swallow up the rest of your file and then, very likely, halt with some mysterious error message.  (Of course, we are assuming that it is much more unlikely to misspell the `\end` keyword itself, also because many editor will supply it automatically.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a macro with a delimited argument to do what you want. But as Bernard says, it's probably better to just configure your editor to insert the full environment.

I didn't look too deeply into it, but I suspect that `\begin{gather}` is looking for `\end{gather}` explicitly. Since it's being hidden inside your `\eg`, it doesn't find it.

Using a macro with a delimited argument looks something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\bg#1\eg{%
    \begin{gather}%
    #1%
    \end{gather}%
}

\begin{document}

\bg
2+2 = 4\\
\frac{\sqrt{y}}{x^2} = a
\eg

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The multi-line display-math environments, such as `gather`, of the `amsmath` package are set up to look for explicit, hard-coded termination strings, e.g., `\end{gather}`, to determine when the end of an environment has been reached. The reason your attempts #1 and #2 cannot work is that LaTeX only "sees" `\eg` and `\egat` while it's scanning ahead to locate the end of the `gather` environment. However, during this scanning-ahead phase, LaTeX does *not* expand any macros and hence doesn't get a chance to "realize" that these macros will expand to `\end{gather}`.

Hence, while it's OK to create LaTeX macros to act as abbreviations for `\begin{gather}` and for the single-line environment `equation`, a macro-based approach will fail for `\egat` and `\eg`. If you are free to use LuaLaTeX, though, you could take a pre-processor approach, as is done in the following example. (In case you're curious about the details: The example code sets up a Lua function which operates at a very early stage of processing. The function scans all input lines and replaces "on the fly" all instances of `\eg` that occur at the very end of a line with `\end{gather}`. Note that the instance of `\eg` in the string `\verb+\eg+` does *not* get operated on by the Lua function.)

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,luacode}

%% OK to create LaTeX shortcut macros for "equation" env.
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}
%% OK to create LaTeX macro to abbreviate "\begin{gather}"
\newcommand{\bg}{\begin{gather}}

%% Preprocessor approach to handle abbrev. for "\end{gather}"
\begin{luacode}
function do_gather ( s )
   return s:gsub ( "\\eg$" , "\\end{gather}" )
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", do_gather , "do_gather" )
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\verb+gather+ environment: \verb+\bg+ and \verb+\eg+
    \bg
        2 + 2 = 4\\ 
        \frac{\sqrt{y}}{x^2} = a
    \eg
\verb+equation+ environment: \verb+\be+ and \verb+\ee+
    \be
        2 + 2 = 4
    \ee
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mico! I chose TH's because he's was simpler and didnt require LuaTex. But yours works too! thank you!!!

Comment: @ivbc -- just remember that if you do this, never try to submit the file in that condition to a journal for publication.  since most journals will not be using lua(la)tex for at least a few years (it's not yet sufficiently stable for their needs) this will fail, and it will no doubt be sent back to you for repairs.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is to define a custom *environment* that one can redefine, once and for all, as, say, either `gather` or `gather*`, as the OP noted in [one of her/his comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373841/how-to-make-shortcuts-for-the-start-and-end-of-a-gather-environment/373849#comment924782_373841) (switching from `gather` to `align`, or vice versa, seems much less sensible, of course!), it should be noted that this—I repeat, for an *environment*—*is* possible, thanks to the code that Michael J. Downes wrote some fifteen/twenty years ago and that, after having being integrated into the `amsmath` package, formed the base of the `environs` package.  Look at the following code for a working example:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment*{mygather}{\gather}{\endgather}
% \newenvironment*{mygather}{\csname gather*\endcsname}{\endgather}
\newenvironment*{myalign}{\align}{\endalign}
% \newenvironment*{myalign}{\csname align*\endcsname}{\endalign}



\begin{document}

A customized \texttt{gather} environment:
\begin{mygather}
    1+1+1+1 = 4\\
    \frac{\sqrt{y}}{x^2} = a
\end{mygather}

A customized \texttt{align} environment:
\begin{myalign}
    1+1+1+1 &= 4\\
    \frac{\sqrt{y}}{x^2} &= a
\end{myalign}

\end{document}
```

You can comment out the two lines that say

```
\newenvironment*{mygather}{\gather}{\endgather}
```

and

```
\newenvironment*{myalign}{\align}{\endalign}
```

and uncomment in their place those that read, respectively,

```
% \newenvironment*{mygather}{\csname gather*\endcsname}{\endgather}
```

and

```
% \newenvironment*{myalign}{\csname align*\endcsname}{\endalign}
```

and check that everything works as expected.

The following points are worth remarking:

1. It is *not* necessary to say, for example,

   ```
   \newenvironment*{myalign}
       {\csname align*\endcsname}
       {\csname endalign*\endcsname}
   ```

   because `\csname endalign*\endcsname` and `\endalign`,
   as well as `\csname endgather*\endcsname` and `\endgather`,
   are perfect synonyms.
2. It would probably seem more obvious to write something like

   ```
   \newenvironment*{mygather}{\begin{gather}}{\end{gather}}
   ```

   but this does ***not*** work.
3. The benefit of a markup like, say,

   ```
   \begin{mygather} ... \end{mygather}
   ```

   over

   ```
   \bgather ... \egather
   ```

   is that the former integrates into LaTeX’s environment system,
   taking advantage of its name-checking facilities; thus, if you
   misspell the name `mygather` in the `\end` declaration, you’ll get a
   meaningful error message. On the other hand, if you misspell an
   argument delimiter like `\egather`, (La)TeX will swallow up the rest
   of your file and then, very likely, halt with some mysterious error
   message.  (Of course, we are assuming that it is much more unlikely
   to misspell the `\end` keyword itself, also because many editors will
   supply it automatically.)